# How to get the elements in DIV which is in a zurb foundation cell to start in new line

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have two elements on div which is in Zurb foundation cell like this

```
<div className="cell small-8 medium-6 large-8 title">
               <h6>title of the item</h6>
               <p>description of the item</p>
    </div>
```

and they are showing in the same line

`title of the item`            `description of the item`

but i want the two elements in different lines

`title of the item`
 `description of the item`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in your code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkj6Lxtr/)). Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Your div is using "className" rather than just "class". Try this change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem just lies in your syntax. Try this:

```
<div class="cell small-8 medium-6 large-8 title">
  <h6>title of the item</h6>
  <p>description of the item</p>
</div>
```